# Parsing a json object with a dynamic field in Kotlin

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a JSON object:

```
{
  "mobileNum": "05x-xxxxxxx", 
   "appId": "some_app", 
   "messageId": "printUsersFirstTime", 
   "shouldSendDate": "2017-10-03T16:20+03:00", // this is optional 
   "paramMap": { "userName": "some_name" }, 
   "filters": { "UNIQUE": false, "RECENT": "{ \"unit\": \"MINUTE\", \"size\": 5 }"
}
```

I use Spring Boot and Kotlin. Spring boot automatically maps the mentioned JSON to the following model bean:

```
data class SmsDto(
    var mobileNum: String? = null,
    val appId: String? = null,
    val messageId: String? = null,
    var paramMap: Map<String, String>? = null,
    var shouldSendDate: Timestamp? = null,
    var filters: Map<String, String>? = defaultFilters
)
```

As you see, the problem I have is with `filters` field, which is a `String`, but may contain another JSON object. So I used a lazy solution of escaping the inner JSON double quotes and then parsing It by myself.

Is there a more standard solution that will allow me to send a proper inner JSON object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot appears to be using Jackson library to work with your data classes and json format. You can use another data class as type of `filters` field.

```
data class SmsDto(
    var mobileNum: String? = null,
    val appId: String? = null,
    val messageId: String? = null,
    var paramMap: Map<String, String>? = null,
    var shouldSendDate: Timestamp? = null,
    var filters: SmsFiltersDto? = defaultFilters
)

data class SmsFiltersDto(
    var yourField: Boolean = false,
    ...
)
```